# How to handle JSON parser errors in ruby

Tags: ruby, json

How do I avoid parsing JSON if the response body will not be in JSON, else it throws a huge exception which I would like to handle

```
      def execute_method(foo)
...

        response = self.class.get("/foo.php", query: query)
        JSON.parse(response.body)
      end
```

Comment: I don't want to parse, I would like to find out before parsing. How should I do that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As @Anthony pointed out, use begin/rescue.

```
begin
  ...
  JSON.parse(response.body)
rescue JSON::ParserError
  # Handle error
end
```

**Update**

To check if a string is a valid json, you can create a method:

```
def valid_json?(string)
  !!JSON.parse(string)
rescue JSON::ParserError
  false
end

valid_json?("abc") #=> false
valid_json?("{}") #=> true
```

Comment: I don't want to parse, I would like to find out before parsing. How should I do that?

Comment: @Rpj I added a method to check if `string` is a valid json. I don't think there is any other way to be absolutely sure, other than trying to successfully parse it.